# Why is every $H^1$ function on the circle this way?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to know, specifically, why is every $H^1$ function which is defined on the circle a absolutely continuous function, with square-integrable derivative defined almost everywhere. I have no references for this: it was a fact that was rapidly mentioned in one text I read. I would also like references to where I can get more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from Sobolev embedding: you have dimension $n=1$ and $p=2$ so the Sobolev conjugate exponent $p^*$ satisfies $\frac{1}{p^*}=\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{1}=-\frac{1}{2}$. Since this is strictly negative, the relevant Sobolev embedding is into the Holder space $C^{0,1/2}$, which consists of Holder continuous functions of exponent $1/2$. This gives you absolute continuity, and hence that the weak derivative (which is *defined* to be in $L^2$) is the same as the classical derivative a.e.

The particular result used here is called Morrey's theorem.

Comment: Thanks for answering! In what book may I find about this?

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I learned from Evans PDE. Any text covering PDE theory or (linear) functional analysis should have it, though.